What is a union dtype in numpy, and how do I define it?
Suppose I have an array like this:
x = np.array([["Hello", 0, 1], ["World", 1, 2]], dtype=np.object_)

I'd like to do better in terms of how I define the dtype for this array. More specifically, I want the array to allocate for each element as many bytes as would be required for the largest element.
This is what I think of as a "union" of types.
The answer to the question c-style union with numpy dtypes? refers to "union dtypes" being allowed in numpy after 1.7+.
This is the relevant section in the numpy documentation. "Union types" documentation refers to (base_dtype, new_dtype)'s documentation in the section on data types titled Specifying and constructing data types.
(base_dtype, new_dtype)'s documentation says something interesting (emphasis mine):

This form also makes it possible to specify struct dtypes with overlapping fields, functioning like the ‘union’ type in C. This usage is discouraged, however, and the union mechanism is preferred.

What precisely is the "union mechanism"? Searching for it in the numpy docs doesn't lead me to anything that stands out clearly as the mechanism being referred to. More importantly, I cannot do something like this in (base_dtype, new_dtype) format: (np.object_, (np.uint32, np.uint32)), because np.object_ cannot be used as a base_dtype.
My best guess at the moment: documentation for numpy states that we can allow the structured array fields to overlap...which would give union like behaviour? After all, the structured arrays docs state (emphasis mine):

For these purposes they support specialized features such as subarrays, nested datatypes, and unions, and allow control over the memory layout of the structure.

The docs have sufficiently confused me around what the preferred mechanism is for making a "union type"...

I don't think this 'union' business helps you.
As I see it you have two choices - create an object dtype array, or a structured array.
Object dtype - the elements are python objects.  No specified type (they could be dicts, lists, etc as well as strings and ints).  Strings are python, ints too, so can be of any size.  Memory use in the array is just that of a pointer (8 bytes each).  Memory use by the elements is determined by python, not by the numpy dtype.
In [175]: x = np.array([["Hello", 0, 1], ["World", 1, 2]], dtype=object)

In [176]: x
Out[176]: 
array([['Hello', 0, 1],
       ['World', 1, 2]], dtype=object)

In [177]: x.shape
Out[177]: (2, 3)

Structured array -  For a string field, we have to specify  a max size.  It won't deduce it from the data.
In [178]: y = np.array([("Hello", 0, 1), ("World", 1, 2)], dtype=[('word','U10'),('a',int),('b',int)])

In [179]: y
Out[179]: 
array([('Hello', 0, 1), ('World', 1, 2)],
      dtype=[('word', '<U10'), ('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])

I could have specified other Un size; and i8 instead of i4.
In [180]: y.shape
Out[180]: (2,)

Access to a column of x:
In [181]: x[:,0]
Out[181]: array(['Hello', 'World'], dtype=object)

Access to a field of y:
In [182]: y['word']
Out[182]: array(['Hello', 'World'], dtype='<U10')

In [183]: x[1]
Out[183]: array(['World', 1, 2], dtype=object)

In [184]: y[1]
Out[184]: ('World', 1, 2)

In [185]: type(_)
Out[185]: numpy.void

In [186]: __.dtype
Out[186]: dtype([('word', '<U10'), ('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])

The elements of y are of type void.
In [187]: x.itemsize    # 8 byte pointers
Out[187]: 8

In [188]: y.itemsize    # 10*4 + 2*4
Out[188]: 48

The talk about union dtypes is specific to these structured arrays, and has nothing to do with object dtype.
It may be possible to define a (np.void, 48) dtype, or maybe something combining the two int32 fields into one.  I believe they can also be used to force alignment, and other conformity with c struct.  But the format and documentation isn't clear.  For most users, structured arrays arise when loading csv files with loadtxt or genfromtxt.
np.array can deduce the longest string container from the input:
In [252]: np.array(['foo', 'foobar', 1.23])
Out[252]: array(['foo', 'foobar', '1.23'], dtype='<U32')

In [253]: np.array(['foo', 'foobar', 1.23], dtype=str)
Out[253]: array(['foo', 'foobar', '1.23'], dtype='<U6')

But it doesn't work when defining a compound dtype:
In [255]: np.array(['foo', 'foobar', 1.23], dtype=np.dtype([('a',str)]))
Out[255]: array([('',), ('',), ('',)], dtype=[('a', '<U')])

For that you have to explicitly define the field size.  In effect, with structured arrays, the record size is set by the compound dtype, and data (list of tuples) is assigned.
Computationally, neigther the object dtype or structured dtype is that useful.  Math doesn't span different field dtypes.

"Computationally, neigther the object dtype or structured dtype is that useful." Indeed. This is a use case Pandas or similar libraries solve. Instead of having rows that numpy can't work with efficiently, use columns that it can.
